# How to remove all spaces in Excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have identified that in data that I have imported, there is a space at the beginning each cell in one column. I cannot just backspace these as there are 1000s of time stamps. The screenshot below shows this.

[image]

How can I remove these spaces without having to do it manually?

Comment: `=TRIM()` function

Comment: Seems a duplicate of this guy:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578397/remove-leading-or-trailing-spaces-in-an-entire-column-of-data   with some good answers over there already

Answer (score 3):

Insert a column next to the timestamps and put this formula in C2 -

```
=TRIM(B2)
```

then drag it down. Now **copy and paste special - values** back to column B and delete C. [Trim](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388fa-c5df-49c6-b16c-9e5630b479f9) KB.

Answer (score 1):

Try this short macro:

```
Sub NoSpace()
   Dim rng As Range, r As Range
   Set rng = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("B:B"))

   For Each r In rng
      If Left(r.Text, 1) = " " Then
         r.Value = Mid(r.Text, 2)
      End If
   Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to trouble with macros, you only expect to do this once, you don't want to have another column, and your dates all come from only one or two years:

- select the column,
- find-replace

" 2016-" with "2016-"  (no quotes, of course)